# Dijkstra shortest path algorithm infinite loop

Tags: graph-theory, dijkstra

Following is the full code of my program. There is something wrong in the dijkstra function whereas when I use an vertex id greater than 18 it stays in infinite loop. I tried different combinations and didn't see any problem so far other than using a number greater than 18. I've added sample "city_list.txt" and "weighted_list.txt" too if you want to compile yourself.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define CITYLIST "city_list.txt"
#define WEIGHTLIST "weight_list.txt"
#define INFINITE 32700
#define MAXV 100

void editfile(FILE *fp);
const char *readLine(FILE *fp);
int citycode(char *string, char **cities, int vertices);
int dijkstra(int weight[MAXV][MAXV], int source, int destination, char **cities, int v);


int menu() {
    printf("1. Shortest distance between point A and point B\n");
    printf("2. Shortest distance to all points from point A\n");
    printf("3. List of city codes\n");
    printf("0. Exit\n");
    int choice;
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    return choice;
}

int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(CITYLIST, "r+");
    editfile(fp);

    char *cities[MAXV]; // To store name of the cities

    char buffer[100];
    memset(buffer, '\0', sizeof(buffer));
    int intbuffer;

    int vertices = 0; // Number of vertices
    readLine(fp); // Pass the first line

    /** Read city names from city_list.txt and save them into
        *cities[100] array. Find the number of vertices      */
    while(1) {
        if( fscanf(fp, "%s %d", buffer, &intbuffer) < 0 )
            break;
        int i = 0;
        for(i = 0; buffer[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            // Count inside buffer
        }
        cities[vertices] = (char *)malloc(i+1);
        memset(cities[vertices], '\0', sizeof(*cities[vertices]));
        strcpy(cities[vertices], buffer);
        vertices++;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    fp = fopen(WEIGHTLIST, "r+");
    editfile(fp);
    readLine(fp); // Pass the first line

    int weight[MAXV][MAXV], i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < MAXV; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < MAXV; j++)
            weight[i][j] = INFINITE;
    char buffer2[100];

    for(i = 0; i < vertices; i++) {
        memset(buffer, '\0', sizeof(buffer));
        memset(buffer2, '\0', sizeof(buffer2));
        fscanf(fp, "%s %s %d", buffer, buffer2, &intbuffer);
        int c1, c2;
        c1 = citycode(buffer, cities, vertices);
        c2 = citycode(buffer2, cities, vertices);
        if(c1 == -1 || c2 == -1)
            return -1;
        weight[c1][c2] = intbuffer;
        weight[c2][c1] = intbuffer;
    }

    int choice = menu();
    while(choice != 0) {
        if(choice == 1) {
            choice = -1;
            int p1, p2;
            printf("Point A: ");
            scanf("%d", &p1);
            printf("Point B: ");
            scanf("%d", &p2);
            printf("\n***************\n");
            dijkstra(weight, p1, p2, cities, vertices);
            printf("***************\n\n");
        } else if (choice == 2) {
            choice = -1;
            int p1;
            printf("Point A: ");
            scanf("%d", &p1);
            int i;
            printf("\n***************\n");
            for(i = 0; i < vertices; i++)
                if(p1 != i)
                    dijkstra(weight, p1, i, cities, vertices);
            printf("***************\n\n");
        } else if (choice == 3) {
            choice = -1;
            int i;
            printf("\n***************\n");
            for(i = 0; i < vertices; i++)
                printf("%d. %s\n", i, cities[i]);
            printf("***************\n\n");
        }
        choice = menu();
    }
    return 0;
}

void editfile(FILE *fp) {
    while(1) {
        char ch = fgetc(fp);
        if(ch == '-') {
            fseek(fp, ftell(fp)-1, SEEK_SET);
            fputc(' ', fp);
            fseek(fp, ftell(fp)-1, SEEK_SET);
        }

        if(ch == EOF)
            break;
    }
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
}

const char *readLine(FILE *fp) {
    int maxlinelength = 32;
    char *line = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * maxlinelength);
    char ch = getc(fp);
    int counter = 0;

    while( ch != '\n' && ch != EOF ) {
        if(counter == maxlinelength) {
            maxlinelength += 32;
            line = realloc(line, maxlinelength);
        }

        line[counter] = ch;
        counter++;
        ch = getc(fp);
    }

    line[counter] = '\0'; // Add null terminator
    realloc(line, counter + 1); // Get rid of extra space
    return line;
}

int citycode(char *string, char **cities, int vertices) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < vertices; i++) {
        if( strcmp(string, cities[i]) == 0 )
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

int dijkstra(int weight[MAXV][MAXV], int source, int destination, char **cities, int v) {

    int distance[MAXV], previous[MAXV], dist, i, minid, min, path[100], p;
    int selected[MAXV] = {0};

    for(i = 0; i < v; i++) {
        distance[i] = INFINITE;
        previous[i] = -1;
    }
    selected[source] = 1; // Source is selected
    distance[source] = 0; // Source to source distance zero

    while( selected[destination] == 0 ) {
        min = INFINITE;
        minid = 0;

        for(i = 0; i < v; i++) {
            dist = distance[source] + weight[source][i];
            printf("weight[%d][%d]: %d\n", source, i, weight[source][i]);
            if( dist < distance[i] && selected[i] == 0 ) {
                distance[i] = dist;
                previous[i] = source;
            } else if ( min > distance[i] && selected[i] == 0 ) {
                min = distance[i];
                if(i == 0)
                    minid = source;
                else
                    minid = i;
            }
        }
        source = minid;
        selected[source] = 1;
    }
    source = destination;
    p = 0;
    while( source != -1 ) {
        path[p] = source;
        source = previous[source];
        p++;
    }
    printf("\n---\n");
    for(i = p-1; i > -1; i--) {
        if(i == 0)
            printf("%s", cities[path[i]]);
        else
            printf("%s -> ", cities[path[i]]);
    }
    printf("\nShortest distance: %d\n---\n\n", distance[destination]);
    return distance[destination];
}
```

city_list.txt

```
City-Code
AAA-1
BBB-2
CCC-3
DDD-4
EEE-5
FFF-6
GGG-7
HHH-8
III-9
JJJ-10
KKK-11
LLL-12
MMM-13
NNN-14
OOO-15
PPP-16
RRR-17
SSS-18
TTT-19
UUU-20
WWW-21
XXX-22
ZZZ-23
```

weight_list.txt

```
City1-City2-Distance
AAA-BBB-124
AAA-CCC-123
AAA-DDD-432
AAA-EEE-653
AAA-FFF-12
BBB-CCC-54
BBB-WWW-325
BBB-XXX-146
CCC-PPP-95
CCC-RRR-69
CCC-SSS-124
DDD-JJJ-642
DDD-SSS-5
DDD-XXX-18
DDD-RRR-301
DDD-HHH-13
EEE-KKK-567
EEE-LLL-120
EEE-MMM-400
EEE-NNN-123
EEE-OOO-542
EEE-PPP-51
XXX-SSS-49
XXX-WWW-39
```

Comment: Correction: It is not about being higher than 18. I use 23 vertexes their ids start from 0 and out of everything between 0 and 22 only 6,8,18,19 and 22 were stuck in infinite loop. I still cannot see what's special about these numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of the algorithm gets stuck when there is no route. There is no exit condition for that from main loop of the algorithm.

If you had properly numbered your cities, you would have seen that as well, probably - as your list of cities is now, numbers there do not correspond to the numbers program actually uses! Please note that there is no edge going to GGG or ZZZ in your list of routes.

One way to fix your algorithm would be to add this explicit clause to your loop. For example:

```
// no vertex actually can have index v, so we can use it as a deadlock condition
while( selected[destination] == 0 && source != v) {
    min = INFINITE;
    minid = v;

    printf("minid = %d\n", minid);
    for(i = 0; i < v; i++) {
        dist = distance[source] + weight[source][i];
        printf("weight[%d][%d]: %d\n", source, i, weight[source][i]);
        if( dist < distance[i] && selected[i] == 0 ) {
            distance[i] = dist;
            previous[i] = source;
        }
        if ( min > distance[i] && selected[i] == 0 ) {
            min = distance[i];
            minid = i;
        }
    }
    selected[source] = 1;
    source = minid;
    getc(stdin);
}
if(selected[destination] == 0 && source == v)
{
    printf("\nThere is no route!\n");
    return distance[destination]; // will be INFINITE
}
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense. If you do it like that while loop will always end as source being "v" so no matter if there is a route or not it will always print there is no route.

Comment: Although thanks for pointing out that the problem was about no route. I fixed it by limiting the main while loop to turn at v times at max. I created a new variable called flag set its value to v and decreased it everytime while worked. And then if flag is zero there is no route.

Comment: It seems you are right; i did not consider proper termination case. However i believe that to be correctable by checking if destination has been processed. Of course, while i believe counter to be sub-optimal (it will run v times even on isolated node when 1 time is enough) it is definitely a working solution